# MYSQL create a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a msyql query where i'll find all  items that have closed & sold but not yet charged to a customer.

Basically, I have a catalog_item which is my product, and once the catalog item closes, we charge the customer, and a record in our customer_order table (there's a column called catalog_item_id which we can join on).

**So I need to:**

1) Find all the active items that closed with bids (covered below in code),

2) Join the customer_order, look at ALL orders and reject any catalog_items in the first part of the query that have a order.

The first part of this query is written below, the second part of the query goes past my sql knowledge and I believe requires a subquery.  I welcome any help in advance!!!!

```
select * 
from catalog_item  as ci
left outer join customer_order as co on co.catalog_item_id = ci.catalog_item_id
where 
  ci.close_date < now()  
  and ci.active = 1
  and ci.bid_count > 0
```

Comment: Some sample data would have been more clear than 10 explanations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "get rid of catalog items that have any orders", you just want to check that the `left join` doesn't find anything:

```
select * 
from catalog_item  as ci left outer join
     customer_order as co
     on co.catalog_item_id = ci.catalog_item_id
where ci.close_date < now() and
      ci.active = 1 and
      ci.bid_count > 0 and
      co.catalog_item_id is null;
```